# GNU Binutils' Binary File Descriptor library - format example

Tags: c, gnu, executable-format, bfd

As in title. I tried reading the BFD's ELF's code, but it's rather not a light reading. I also tried to get something from the documentation, but I would need an example to see how it works. Could anyone point me some easier example for me, to know how to define an executable format?

**Edit**: Looks like I didn't formulate the question properly. I don't ask "how to create own executable format specification?", nor "where is good ELF documentation?", but "how can I implement my own executable format using GNU BFD?".

Comment: Your question now makes less sense, not more..... can you expand on that some more?

Comment: I want to be able to compile my programs using GNU toolchain, but executable should be generated in format defined by me.

Comment: OK, I understand you now. Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did look here http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/bfd/index.html and here http://sourceware.org/binutils/binutils-porting-guide.txt?

Also studying the MMO implementation of a BFD backend as mentioned here http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/bfd/mmo.html#mmo (source: http://sourceware.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb.cgi/src/bfd/mmo.c?cvsroot=src) might be less complex than starting with ELF ... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that BFD documentation is somewhat lacking.  Here are some better sources:

- [ELF Format](http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf)
- [System V ABI](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/gabi41.pdf) (section 4)

Here are a couple of readable introductions:

- [Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/1059)
- [Dr. Dobbs](http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/184410191)

And some examples that don't use libbfd:

- [ELF IO](http://elfio.sourceforge.net/)
- [ELF Toolchain](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/)
- [LibELF](http://wiki.freebsd.org/LibElf)

Comment: Hmm, I think I must reformulate my question. I don't ask "how to create own executable format specification", nor "where is good ELF documentation", but "how can I implement my own executable format using GNU BFD".

Answer (score 1):

The DOS COM file is the simplest possible format.

Load up to 64k less 256 bytes at seg:0100h, set DS,ES,SS=seg, SP=FFFFh and jump to seg:0100h

Comment: Hmm, but the binutils' msdos format lack some features... and as most gnu code, lack almost any documentation - assuming I should always know what is going on, when reading the code.